# Using GDAL and ogr utilities in MAC terminal in conjunction with QGIS

Tags: bash, gis, gdal, ogr

I am pretty new to the open-source GIS software.  I am trying to clip and project data layers using GDAL and ogr in my MAC terminal.  I can get the data to clip when I am just clipping but when I try and combine the two (clip and project), I am getting a syntax error.  The syntax I have was written for Command Line and I'm thinking I may need to tweak it for terminal.  Any help would be greatly appreciated! If someone is willing to help, I will try and provide more information if necessary.

Here is my line of code:

```
$for %X in (*.shp) do ogr2ogr -skipfailures -clipsrc
~/Desktop/PhiladelphiaBaseLayers/clipFeature/city_limits.shp
~/Desktop/PhiladelphiaBaseLayers/clipped/%X
~/Desktop/PhiladelphiaBaseLayers/%X
```

When I run the code, I receive this error message:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switcher from windows to mac? ;)

If I understand right your intent is run the `ogr2ogr` with 3 file arguments

try the next

```
for shpfile in *.shp
do
    echo ogr2ogr -skipfailures -clipsrc \
       ~/Desktop/PhiladelphiaBaseLayers/clipFeature/city_limits.shp \
       ~/Desktop/PhiladelphiaBaseLayers/clipped/"$shpfile" \
       ~/Desktop/PhiladelphiaBaseLayers/"$shpfile"
done
```

when you satisfied, remove the `echo`

Comment: Thank you! Actually, I've used a MAC most of my life.  I've just recently started a technology degree (I have a Biology background), and I'm still getting used to terminal.  :) So I ran the new code and came up with this error                                FAILURE: Couldn't fetch requested layer '/Users/ashleyhaynes/Desktop/PhiladelphiaBaseLayers/atms.shp'!

Comment: Also, when I type ogrinfo I am receiving this

$ ogrinfo
Usage: ogrinfo [--help-general] [-ro] [-q] [-where restricted_where]
               [-spat xmin ymin xmax ymax] [-geomfield field] [-fid fid]
               [-sql statement] [-dialect sql_dialect] [-al] [-so] [-fields={YES/NO}]
               [-geom={YES/NO/SUMMARY}][--formats]
               datasource_name [layer [layer ...]]

FAILURE: No datasource specified.

Comment: Thank you for your help!! I ended up getting it to work!!  So I would use something like "$shpfile" in place of %X? correct? Thanks again!!!

Comment: @AshleyHanes search google for "basic bash" and you will find many guides... [like this](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html) good luck with bash programming.

Answer (score 1):

This is what ultimately worked for me. Take out the quotations around the variable call. All one line.

for f in *.shp; do ogr2ogr -skipfailures -clipsrc ~/documents/PhiladelphiaBaseLayers/clipFeature/city_limits.shp ~/documents/PhiladelphiaBaseLayers/clipped/$f ~/documents/PhiladelphiaBaseLayers/$f; done